# Problems with X11 forwarding

Tags: ssh, cygwin, xorg, putty, x11-forwarding

I am trying to do some X11 forwarding from my windows machine. I have tried:

- Mingw64
- Cygwin64
- putty

In both Mingw and cygwin I run I get these results:

```
$ ssh -X bongioc@ncp-cb-1.nintextest.com
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-62-generic x86_64)
Last login: Tue Sep  1 13:20:14 2015 from 10.5.4.83
bongioc@ncp-cb-1:~$ firefox

(process:13343): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified
bongioc@ncp-cb-1:~$ xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
bongioc@ncp-cb-1:~$ export DISPLAY=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}'`:0
bongioc@ncp-cb-1:~$ echo $DISPLAY
10.5.4.83:0
bongioc@ncp-cb-1:~$ xterm
No protocol specified
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 10.5.4.83:0
bongioc@ncp-cb-1:~$
```

None of this works. But, if I use putty and select X11 forwarding, it just works.

I would prefer not use putty. Can someone explain how I can get mingw (preferred) or cygwin to actually forward X11 correctly? I am using **xming** for my xserver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For msys(mingw64), after running Xming, you need to set your $DISPLAY value before running ssh with X forwarding.

I haven't checked cygwin but I guess it's the same(although you'd probably want to run the cygwin X11 server).

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0
ssh username@server -X
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the display variable as jbcreix suggested by running
`export DISPLAY=localhost:0`
I also had to use `-Y` instead of `-X`.

From the man page:

```
-Y
    Enables trusted X11 forwarding. Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.
```

It disables some security checks and should only be used when logging in on trusted hosts.
It is claimed that the security checks are not useful anyway [here](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#remote) and [here](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-xfree/2008-11/msg00154.html). Ubuntu used -Y by default even for -X for a long time according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35512/what-is-the-difference-between-ssh-y-trusted-x11-forwarding-and-ssh-x-u#35518).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and found that MinGW64 is a separate from XMing, which also needs to be installed.  After installing and running XMing, an ssh from a MinGW window to a Linux server fixed my problem.  X forwarding now works.